# AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'hist'

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, histogram, attributeerror

I'm new to Python (and am using Spyder) and am trying to create some histograms of when the top movies from IMDB were created. I have imported the matplotlib, numpy and pandas, as well as the .txt file, but when I run the following lines of code:

```
plt.hist(data.year, bins=np.arange(1950, 2013), color='#cccccc')
```

I receive an error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "stdin", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'hist'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: post the entire code

Comment: As an aside you could just call `plot` on the df: `df.plot(kind='hist')` see the docs: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html#pandas.DataFrame.plot

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Your question provide very poor information and insight in your code. More data..

Meanwhile check if you actually import your modules correctly, should have:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

in order to use `hist` function

Comment: several common example books and cookbooks are still using 'pylab.'  I've had similar troubles with pylab, usually cured by the recipe above `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt` then replacing `pylab` with `plt` everywhere.